# How to use await in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm trying to create an asynchronous console app that does a some work on a collection. I have one version which uses parallel for loop another version that uses async/await. I expected the async/await version to work similar to parallel version but it executes synchronously. What am I doing wrong?

```cs
public class Program 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        var worker = new Worker();
        worker.ParallelInit();
        var t = worker.Init();
        t.Wait();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Worker 
{
    public async Task<bool> Init() 
    {
        var series = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
        foreach(var i in series) 
        {
          Console.WriteLine("Starting Process {0}", i);
          var result = await DoWorkAsync(i);
          
          if (result) 
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Ending Process {0}", i);
          }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DoWorkAsync(int i) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("working..{0}", i);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        
        return true;
    }

    public bool ParallelInit() 
    {
        var series = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
        
        Parallel.ForEach(series, i => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting Process {0}", i);
            DoWorkAsync(i);
            Console.WriteLine("Ending Process {0}", i);
        });
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The way you're using the `await` keyword tells C# that you want to wait each time you pass through the loop, which isn't parallel. You can rewrite your method like this to do what you want, by storing a list of `Task`s and then `await`ing them all with [`Task.WhenAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194766.aspx).

```
public async Task<bool> Init()
{
    var series = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
    var tasks = new List<Task<Tuple<int, bool>>>();
    foreach (var i in series)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Process {0}", i);
        tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(i));
    }
    foreach (var task in await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
    {
        if (task.Item2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ending Process {0}", task.Item1);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public async Task<Tuple<int, bool>> DoWorkAsync(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("working..{0}", i);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return Tuple.Create(i, true);
}
```

Comment: I don't know about others, but a parallel for/foreach seems more straight forward for parallel loops.

Comment: Important to note that when you see the `Ending Process` notification **isn't** when the task is actually ending. All of those notifications are dumped out sequentially right after the *last* of the tasks finishes. By the time you see "Ending Process 1", process 1 might have been over for a long time. Other than the choice of words there, +1.

Comment: @Brettski I may be wrong, but a parallel loop traps any sort of async result.  By returning a Task<T> you immediately get back a Task object in which you can manage the work that is going on inside such as cancelling it or seeing exceptions. Now with Async/Await you can work with the Task object in a more friendly manner - that is you don't have to do Task.Result.

Comment: @Tim S, what if I want to return a value with async function using Tasks.WhenAll method?

Comment: Would it be a bad practice to implement a `Semaphore` in `DoWorkAsync` to limit the maximum executing tasks?

Comment: What if i invoke the DoWorkAsync like Task.Run inside for each , is that a bad practice  ?

Comment: This is fantastic, thanks for the clarification code. I've added Task Delays throughout the code to identify the described parallel behaviour and this just made it a lot clearer

Comment: Say the for loop enumerates over 10000 records. Say the present iteration is 6000 and at this point one of the initial task (Say task 1) has finished awaiting the Task.Delay. Now, at this point, will the code below await in Task 1 run immediately or will it wait for entire for loop to complete? Would this behavior differ whether it is a console app or a windows forms app?

Answer (score 42):

Your code waits for each operation (using `await`) to finish before starting the next iteration.
Therefore, you don't get any parallelism.

If you want to run an existing asynchronous operation in parallel, you don't need `await`; you just need to get a collection of `Task`s and call `Task.WhenAll()` to return a task that waits for all of them:

```
return Task.WhenAll(list.Select(DoWorkAsync));
```

Comment: so you cant use any asynchronous methods in any loops?

Comment: @Satish: You can.  However, `await` does the exact opposite of what you want – it _waits_ for the `Task` to finish.

Comment: I wanted to accept your answer but Tims S has a better answer.

Comment: Or if you don't need to know when the task finished you can just call the methods without awaiting for them

Comment: To confirm what that syntax is doing - it's running the Task called `DoWorkAsync` on each item in `list` (passing each item into `DoWorkAsync`, which I assume has a single parameter)?

Comment: how do you collect tasks?

Answer (score 14):

```
public async Task<bool> Init()
{
    var series = Enumerable.Range(1, 5);
    Task.WhenAll(series.Select(i => DoWorkAsync(i)));
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In C# 7.0 [you can use semantic names to each of the members of the tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#tuples), here is [Tim S.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19431767/3367974)'s answer using the new syntax:

```
public async Task<bool> Init()
{
    var series = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).ToList();
    var tasks = new List<Task<(int Index, bool IsDone)>>();

    foreach (var i in series)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Process {0}", i);
        tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(i));
    }

    foreach (var task in await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
    {
        if (task.IsDone)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ending Process {0}", task.Index);
        }
    }

    return true;
}

public async Task<(int Index, bool IsDone)> DoWorkAsync(int i)
{
    Console.WriteLine("working..{0}", i);
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return (i, true);
}
```

You could also get rid of `task.` *inside `foreach`*:

```
// ...
foreach (var (IsDone, Index) in await Task.WhenAll(tasks))
{
    if (IsDone)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Ending Process {0}", Index);
    }
}
// ...
```

Comment: Say the for loop enumerates over 10000 records. Say the present iteration is 6000 and at this point one of the initial task (Say task 1) has finished awaiting the Task.Delay. Now, at this point, will the code below await in Task 1 run immediately or will it wait for entire for loop to complete? Would this behavior differ whether it is a console app or a windows forms app?

Comment: I get `Warning    CS4014    Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.` when in a _async method_,  ***foreach loop call sync method***

Answer (score 1):

We can use async method in foreach loop to run async API calls.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{

List<ZoneDetails> lst = GetRecords();

    foreach (var item in lst)
    {
        //For loop run asyn
        var result = GetAPIData(item.ZoneId, item.fitnessclassid).Result;
        if (result != null && result.EventHistoryId != null)
        {
            UpdateDB(result);
        }
    }
}

private static async Task<FODBrandChannelLicense> GetAPIData(int zoneId, int fitnessclassid)
{

    HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

    var response = HttpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url)).Result;

    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>(content);

    if (response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"API Call completed successfully");

    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Try `async` in **Main method** ?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already good answers here, it's always helpful to me to remember that the async method returns a *Task*.

So in the example in this question, each iteration of the loop has `await`. This causes the `Init()` method to return control to its caller *with a `Task<bool>` - not a bool.*

Thinking of await as just a magic word that causes execution state to be saved, then skipped to the next available line until ready, encourages confusion: "why doesn't the for loop just skip the line with await and go to the next statement?"

If instead you think of await as something more like a yield statement, that brings a `Task` with it when it returns control to the caller, in my opinion flow starts to make more sense: "the for loop stops at await, and returns control and the `Task` to the caller. The for loop won't continue until that is done."

Comment: The official docs have a lot to say on this, one place that demonstrates using a loop is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async#wait-for-multiple-tasks-to-complete