# Using IEnumerator for async operation on items

Tags: c#, ienumerator

I am using some API that returns me an `IEnumerator` child Instance i want to do some function on each object returned

I usualy use

```
while(Enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    DoSomething(Enumerator.current);
}
```

I don't have `IEnumerable` Object 
and I want to `DoSomething` with each object asynchronously

I don't want to get `IEnumerable` from `IEnumerator` for performance issues.

What else can i do to loop async with `IEnumerator`

Comment: It's not clear if you want to fetch items asynchronously or DoSomething asynchronously.

Comment: both if possible but mostly DoSomething

Comment: Then nothing stops you from doing `await DoSomething(Enumerator.current)`.

Comment: And if by "asynchronously" you meant "in parallel", then see https://stackoverflow.com/q/19431494/11683.

Answer (score 5):

[C# 8.0 has Async Enumerable feature](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/01/09/iasyncenumerable-in-c-8/).

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await foreach (var dataPoint in FetchIOTData())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dataPoint);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> FetchIOTData()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);//Simulate waiting for data to come through. 
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use that in VS2017

Comment: [You can't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54701377/c-sharp-8-0-availability-in-visual-studio-2017). it's not backward-compatible technology. It is also still in beta. Upgrade to VS2019 and use it.

Comment: Interesting, but distinct from an IEnumerator, no?